# I would like to count the number of users who made multiple purchases grouped by month

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

So what i'm trying to do here, is that i am trying to count the number of repeat users (users who made more than one order) in a period of time, let it be month day or year, the case here is months

i'm currently running mysql mariadb and i'm pretty much a beginner in mysql, i've tried multiple subqueries but all have failed till now

This is what i have tried so far ..

This returns all the number of users with no ordering count condition

Since people are asking for sample data, here is what the data is looking like at the moment:

```
Order_Creation_Date - User_ID - Order_ID

2019-01-01              123         1
2019-01-01              123         2
2019-01-01              231         3
2019-01-01              231         4
```

This is the query i am using to get the result but it keeps on returning total number of users within the month

```
select month(o.created_at)month,
year(o.created_at)year,
count(distinct o.user_uuid) from orders o
group by month(o.created_at)
having count(*)>1
```

and this returns the number of users as 1 ..

```
select month(o.created_at)month,
year(o.created_at)year,
(select count(distinct ord.user_uuid) from orders ord
 where ord.user_uuid = o.user_uuid 
 group by ord.user_uuid
 having count(*)>1) from orders o
group by month(o.created_at)
```

Expected result will be from the sample data above

```
Month Count of repeat users
1              2
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I think you need to group by year as well as month. Also as @Gordon said, sample data would help a lot. And I don't know what you mean when you say what the queries you have posted return, because you did not show what they returned. You just tell us.

Comment: An expected result without a sample data set is beyond daft. You can see that, right? We

Comment: Hey guys, added sample data and expected result from sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the number of users that make more than one purchase in January, then do two levels of aggregations:  one by user and month and the other by month:

```
select yyyy, mm, sum( num_orders > 1) as num_repeat_users
from (select year(o.created) as yyyy, month(o.created) as mm,
             o.user_uuid, count(*) as num_orders
      from orders o
      group by yyyy, mm, o.user_uuid
     ) o
group by yyyy, mm;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try something like this which will return USer_ID list Month and Year wise who ordered more that once for the period-

```
SELECT 
[user_uuid],
MONTH(o.created_at) month, 
YEAR(o.created_at) year, 
COUNT(o.user_uuid)
FROM orders o
GROUP BY 
MONTH(o.created_at),YEAR(o.created_at)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

For more, if you are looking for the count that how many users placed more that one order, you can just place the above query as a sub query and make a count on column 'user_uuid'